# Do you have the right to burn your own books?

Tags: jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names

There are stories of Rabbis who have composed works only later to burn or otherwise willfully destroy them (Rabbi Nachman and The Kotzker Rebbi come to mind). I would understand if they had these works buried as sheimos, but what gives them the right to actually burn divrei torah?

Rebbi Nachman - [Sefer HaNisraf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachman_of_Breslov#Published_works)

[The Kotzker](http://kotzk.com/2012/03/03/kotzker-story-1/) (Actually the Chiddushei HaRim)

Comment: Can you cite these stories?

Comment: asifahnik, welcome to the site and thanks for the interesting question (which can, as Double AA noted, be improved with a reference to the stories you mention). I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Please consider [registering](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login) your [account](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/1520), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: This issue is dealt with in one of R' Rakeffet's most recent classes ([link to audio](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/775209/Rabbi_Aaron_Rakeffet-Rothkoff/2012-5-6_Responsa_25_The_Netziv_Saves_the_Responsa_of_German_Jewry)). I'd have to re-listen to get all the details, but I recall that a German rabbi directed that his works be burnt after his death, but the Netziv ruled that his family could override his directive for the sake of preserving Torah thoughts. Listen there for the details and sources in both directions.

Comment: The Alter Rebbe also burned his sefer shel tzaddikim. Another story is that he had it bound on both sides so no one could open it.

Comment: @mochinrechavim I thought it was burned in one of the relatively common "city fires" that took place then?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That was the Alter Rebbe's Shuchan Aruch.

Comment: @mochinrechavim There is a famous story how after it got burned, the Alter Rebbe asked the Mitteler Rebbe if he ever looked at it. When he replied in the negative (since there was a Cherem of Rabbeinu Gershon on reading it), the Alter Rebbe said "What about Mesirus Nefesh for Torah"?

Comment: It seems implicit that at least the Kotzker felt it was right to do so, and obviously the Chidushei HaRim and Rebbe Nachman zchusam yagen alenu felt it was permitted.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, _Rabenu Gershom_ put a _cherem_ on reading something the _baal haTanya_ wrote?

Comment: @msh210 maybe it is like a private letter

Comment: @msh210 the Alter Rebbe wrote (on the cover) that one isn't allowed to read it by force of the Cherem Derabeinu Gershon

Comment: @msh210 see http://books.google.com/books?id=NnyuhrzRDCMC&lpg=PA305&vq=in%20this%20world&pg=PA364#v=onepage&q=rabbeinu%20gershon&f=false

Comment: @mochinrechavim you too can look. However, he doesn't mention that this was the sefer shel tzaddikim. It is possible that these were two different books.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I have a messorah that it was Sefer Shel Tzaddikim. No proof outside of that.

Comment: @user1292 The Alter Rebbe burned a commentary on Chumash he compiled in his youth, as recounted [here](http://www.beismoshiach.org/Holidays/11Nissan274.htm). I don't think the Sefer Shel Tzaddikim was burned deliberately.